# Java calling method in another class

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Java class with certain number of pizzas that decreases in number

if someone steals it.

I have two classes.

class House where pizza is,

```
public class House {
    private static int totalPizzas;

    public House() {
        totalPizzas = totalPizzas;
    }

    public int getTotalPizzas() {
        return totalPizzas;
    }

    public static void setTotalPizzas(int totalPizzas) {
        totalPizzas = totalPizzas - Thief.stealPizza(House stolenPizza);
    }    
}
```

and class Thief that steals the pizza.

```
public class Thief {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Thief() {
        name = "abc";
        age = 11;
    }

    public static void stealPizza(House stolenPizza) {
        ??????? 
    }   
}
```

My main concern is the ??????? part where I feel like I should set stolenPizza to certain

integers but

```
stolenPizza = 1;
```

certainly does not work.

Could someone give me a bit of advice on how I should approach this?

Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: Make a main class that have object of both class. You probably don't need any static methods besides main

Comment: `Thief.stealPizza(House stolenPizza)` is not valid syntax for a method call. And you can't call a method that returns `void` as part of an arithmetic expression

Comment: Is there a reason that some of these methods are static?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to do something like:

```
 public class Thief {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        public Thief() {
            name = "abc";
            age = 11;
        }

        public static void stealPizza() {
           House.setTotalPizzas(House.totalPizzas - 1);
        }   
    }


public class House {
   private static int totalPizzas;

   public House() {
       totalPizzas = totalPizzas;
   }

   public int getTotalPizzas() {
       return totalPizzas;
   }

   public static void setTotalPizzas(int totalPizzas) {
       House.totalPizzas = totalPizzas;
   }    
}
```

Comment: Though static methods make no sense.

Comment: I can see the value. There is no relation between the `house` and the `thief`. What if a `Thief` wants to steal jewels? What they donate pizza? A better option might be to create a singleton to manage the pizza count, but again, this is just one way to do it. Also, without more context who is to say it isn't the right option; let alone suggest a new way.

Comment: For thief maybe (Assuming there is only one thief) but not for House. A thief can steal pizzas from multiple homes

Comment: Do you know there are multiple homes? Maybe it's a "Pizza house" restaurant.

Comment: Fair enough but shouldn't getter be static as well?

Comment: Depends on where you use the getter.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is missing something if I understand your code right:

Your code

```
 public House() {
            totalPizzas = totalPizzas;
 }
```

will set the amount of totalPizzas on itself without assigning any "real" integer value to it. Try

```
 public House(int totalPizzas) {
            totalPizzas = totalPizzas;
 }
```

so that you actually can assign a number of Pizzas to the house when calling the constructor, for example:

```
House house = new House (12);
```

if you want to have 12 Pizzas in the house.